# What causes a FileSystemWatcher object to go stale?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a FileSystemWatcher that processes files based on file system events.  After awhile, the process is still alive, but it no longer detects the file system events.  The process watches a local network share drive.

Anything I should be watching out for?

Comment: Did you implement the Error event?

Comment: Are you handling the error event for the FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: thanks, I guess it's an "obvious" thing that I missed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely small drops in network connectivity. Check [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/eventsanddelegates/article.php/c9113/).

Basically:

- set `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true`
- add an event handler to `watcher.Error`

Then re-bind on error.

Comment: thanks, sounds like a good thing to try, since i'm sure i don't watch for it.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I had an "The network BIOS command limit has been reached" which can easily be googled.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I better post the answer instead of leaving it in the comment: did you implement the Error event?  When you do get errors, bump up the value of the InternalBufferSize property.  Try 16384.

Answer (score 1):

http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/536125-filesystemwatcher-across-network